# How to get the image from Chrome(Intermediate D3D Window),by use gdi and HWND?

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, gdi, direct3d

I use `gdi32.dll` to get the image from the process window handle,The code written in C# on Windows 10, like this:

```cs
    DC = GetWindowDC(HWND);
    CDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DC);
    CB = CreateCompatibleBitmap(DC, 1920, 1080);
    SelectObject(CDC, CB);
    BitBlt(CDC, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, DC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    GetBitmapBits(CB, 1920*1080*4, BitImageArray);
```

Then the `BitImageArray[]` will be filled with image RGBA data.

For the most part, it works fine until I try to get the Chrome window image, then it doesn't work.

I use SPY++ to see the class name of the Chrome window, it's named "Intermediate D3D Window"

Looks like it has something to do with GPU acceleration.

When I turned off GPU acceleration, I noticed that the Chrome window class name changed to "Chrome Legacy Window", then it worked again

But the target page can only be displayed when GPU acceleration is turned on.

So how can I use the handle to get image data from "Intermediate D3D Window"?

Comment: That code takes me back.  _"until I try to get...Chrome window image...class name...Chrome window...named 'Intermediate D3D Window'"_ - are you by chance using a _laptop?_  Try running it on a regular PC with a Windows 10+ compliant video card.   The reason I say that is laptops are known to have weird mobile versions of video cards and its entirely possible that the D3D window **isn't** mapped to the same video memory the rest of your display is sitting in.   (remember the days ~2003 where PC-based DVD players would quite happily play a movie but the window was like a green screen merger.

Comment: ....so pressing **Print Screen** would result in a lovely screen shot of Windows but a big black void where the movie would be sitting.   Try pressing **Print Screen** with Chrome running with GPU acceleration and paste the results into _Windows Paint._  Tell us what happens.

Comment: @MickyD That was probably a video overlay but that should not happen with DWM.

Comment: @Anders ah yes.  Goodo.